# How to use NOT IN from a CSV file in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I use Spark sql to load data into a `val` like this

```
val customers = sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM customers")
```

But I have a separate txt file that contains one column `CUST_ID` and 50,00 rows. i.e.

```
CUST_ID
1
2
3
```

I want my `customers` val to have all customers in `customers` table that are not in the TXT file.

Using Sql I would do this by `SELECT * FROM customers NOT IN cust_id ('1','2','3')`

How can I do this using Spark?

I've read the textFile and I can print rows of it but I'm not sure how to match this with my sql query

```
scala> val custids = sc.textFile("cust_ids.txt")
scala> custids.take(4).foreach(println)
CUST_ID
1
2
3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can import your text file as a dataframe and do a left outer join:

```
val customers = Seq(("1", "AAA", "shipped"), ("2", "ADA", "delivered") , ("3", "FGA", "never received")).toDF("id","name","status")
val custId = Seq(1,2).toDF("custId")

customers.join(custId,'id === 'custId,"leftOuter")
         .where('custId.isNull)
         .drop("custId")
         .show()


+---+----+--------------+
| id|name|        status|
+---+----+--------------+
|  3| FGA|never received|
+---+----+--------------+
```

Comment: I get this error in my spark-shell trying to re-create your example: `val test1 = Seq(1,2).toDF("custId")` error: `error: value toDF is not a member of Seq[Int]`

Comment: Are you using a pre 2.0 version  of Spark? Then sc.parallelize(Seq(1,2)).toDF("custId")

Comment: My spark version is `version 1.5.0` and scala version is `Using Scala version 2.10.4`

Comment: I added another question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40534744/error-not-found-value-spark-in-spark-shell